# kineticjs snaping rect into another rect

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I'm using kineticjs to try and drag a small rect into a larger rect and have it snap into place. However, I get an error when I try to use:

```
stage.getUserPosition()
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRmBt/) of what I was trying to do.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or show a better way to get drag and snapping to work? 
p.s. please don't just send me a link to the animal snapping example on html5canvastutorials as I've seen that and it deals with images and I'm dealing with shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do box2.setX and box2.setY, you must also redraw your layer--layer.draw().

```
box2.on("dragend",function(){
    if(isInside(this)){
        box2.setX(box.getX());
        box2.setY(box.getY());
        layer.draw();
    }
});
```

Since your design is so simple, just use rectangular bounds checking to see if box2 is inside box:

```
var dropLeft=box.getX();
var dropRight=dropLeft+box.getWidth();
var dropTop=box.getY();
var dropBottom=dropTop+box.getHeight();

function isInside(shape){
    var x=box2.getX();
    var y=box2.getY();
    var w=box2.getWidth();
    var h=box2.getHeight();
    return(x>=dropLeft && x+w<=dropRight && y>=dropTop && y+h<=dropBottom);
}
```

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ymhfM/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // I use a helper function to build Kinetic rectangles
    // You can do it manually if you want to
    var box=kRect(50,100,100,100,"white","green",6,layer);
    var box2=kRect(10,10,30,30,"lightgray","skyblue",3,layer);

    var dropLeft=box.getX();
    var dropRight=dropLeft+box.getWidth();
    var dropTop=box.getY();
    var dropBottom=dropTop+box.getHeight();

    function isInside(shape){
        var x=box2.getX();
        var y=box2.getY();
        var w=box2.getWidth();
        var h=box2.getHeight();
        return(x>=dropLeft && x+w<=dropRight && y>=dropTop && y+h<=dropBottom);
    }

    box2.on("dragmove",function(){
        if(isInside(this)){
            this.setStroke("red");
        }else{
            this.setStroke("skyblue");
        }
    });

    box2.on("dragend",function(){
        if(isInside(this)){
            box2.setX(box.getX());
            box2.setY(box.getY());
            layer.draw();
        }
    });


    // build the specified KineticJS Rectangle and add it to the stage
    function kRect(x,y,width,height,fill,stroke,strokewidth,layer){
      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        strokeWidth: strokewidth,
        draggable:true
      });    
      layer.add(rect);
      stage.draw();
      return(rect);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome fiddle and explanation marke! thanks! I was wondering though, if you had some more time, any idea on how I can make the inner boxes stack? so if say I had like 4 of them, and I started dragging them in, instead of having them overlap, I want them to stack one on top of another? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated....a fiddle even more so :p

Comment: To align the snaps, use a variable that accumulates widths (or heights) to offset the “snap”.  Like this Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LnwsY/

Comment: Hi, this last fiddle is great, I was wondering how I can drag the blue rectangle with the little ones inside of it (using Kinetic.Group)

Comment: @Sahar Regarding dragging: Create a draggable group and put the big green rect inside that group.  Then when any smaller rect snaps into position, move that smaller rect into the group too.  That way when the group is dragged the smaller rects will be dragged also. When you drag the group, you'll have to adjust the dropzone variables (dropLeft,dropRight,dropTop,dropBottom).  Cheers!